# Trouble with Dropdown onChanged not dismissing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a `office-ui-fabric-react` dropdown:

```
<Dropdown 
    options={hours}
    placeHolder={"Hour"}
    onChanged={(option: IDropdownOption) => {
        this._onChangeHour(option.key+"", field.timePeriod, field.date);
    }}
/>
```

I know it is not best practice to have a function on the callback.  I'm fairly new and coded myself into a corner with this.  I'd prefer not to have to redo a lot of other stuff to follow best practice.

The issue is when I selected a dropdown item, the dropdown menu is not being dismissed.  The `onChanged` doesn't have a promise or anything, so I don't know how to get the dropdown menu to dismiss now.

If I just pass it a class function to run, it will dismiss.  I tried adding `return` to the end of the function but that did nothing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what do u mean by "dismiss"?

Comment: @NiritLevi for the dropdown menu to disappear.

Comment: could it be that the first argument of the callback is not the dropdownoption, and the function throws an error or never fulfilled ?

Comment: @NiritLevi Oh man, I am I ever an idiot.  I had an error that was popping up but missed it.  Right now, my SharePoint sandbox is throwing a POST 429 error because it can't connect to some api/collection about every 2 seconds and its spamming me.  Thanks for the mention on checking for an error.  I appreciate it.